# How to convert wstring into byte vector

Tags: c++, type-conversion, byte, wstring

Hi I have a few typedefs:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef std::vector<Byte> ByteVector;
typedef std::wstring String;
```

I need to convert `String` into `ByteVector`, I have tried this:

```
String str = L"123";
ByteVector vect(str.begin(), str.end());
```

As a result `vectror` contains 3 elements: 1, 2, 3. However it is `wstring` so every charcter in this string is wide so my expected result would be: 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3.

Is there any standart way to do that or I need to write some custom function.

Comment: Hmm. You are allowed to cast any object pointer to a `char*` and access the bytes through it (no guarantees about interpreting them though), and `unsigned char` is required to have the same size and alignment requirements as `char`. So you are legally allowed to do `vect((Byte*)str.data(), ((Byte*)str.data())+(sizeof(wchar_t)*str.size()));`. Wouldn't call that a "good idea" though.

Comment: @BoBTFish Why wouldn't it be a good idea?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to do it with regular iterators. The next issue is the endianness you want in your byte vector. If you just want machine endianness, you can just use `reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char* >` on your iterators (or the pointer returned by `data()`) before initializing your vector. If you want a specific endianness, you'll have to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @jrok I don't like to play that close to undefined behaviour. I didn't say it was necessarily a bad idea either. I just would not like to write it.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Breaking const-correctness is evil (string::data() returns a const pointer). This, my friends, is why C-style casts are bad.

Comment: For example, on different platforms same string can transform to different vectors, because endianness may be different. Even size of result vector can different - sizeof(wchar_t) can be 2 or 4. So, need know where can use this trick.

Comment: @Medinoc That's why it's a comment to suggest an idea, not a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Byte const* p = reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&str[0]);
std::size_t size = str.size() * sizeof(str.front());
ByteVector vect(p, p+size);
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Get this `'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'Byte *'`

Comment: @user2623967 ,My bad, try now.

Comment: Note that it doesn't necessarily give the expected output : `0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3` as it depends on the endianness of the machine. It might give `1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0` on other machines.

Comment: It's a bit odd that you went with `Byte const*` instead of `const Byte*`, the latter indicating that what is pointed to is constant (rather than pointer itself) which is a more common use case. Also `str->data()` would be more elegant than `&str[0]`.

Comment: @mallwright `T const*` and `const T*` are the same thing, you're thinking of `T* const`. I agree about `data()`, but that only came to be with C++11, and not everybody was already using it in 2013 - or maybe I didn't yet know about it back then :)

Answer (score 2):

What is your actual goal? If you just want to get the bytes representing the `wchar_t` objects, a fairly trivial conversion would do the trick although I wouldn't use just a cast to to `unsigned char const*` but rather an explicit conversion.

On the other hand, if you actually want to convert the `std::wstring` into a sequence encoded using e.g. UTF8 or UTF16 as is usually the case when dealing with characters, the conversion used for the encoding becomes significantly more complex. Probably the easiest approach to convert to an encoding is to use C's `wcstombs()`:

```
std::vector<char> target(source.size() * 4);
size_t n = wcstombs(&target[0], &source[0], target.size());
```

The above fragment assumes that `source` isn't empty and that the last `wchar_t` in `source` is `wchar_t()`. The conversion uses C's global locale and assumes to convert whatever character encoding is set up there. There is also a version `wcstombs_l()` where you can specify the locale.

C++ has similar functionality but it is a bit harder to use in the `std::codecvt<...>` facet. I can provide an example if necessary.